# Case classes with inheritance and default parameters

Tags: scala, inheritance

Is there an elegant way in Scala to use case classes (or case classish syntax) with inheritance and default constructor parameters? I kind of want to do this (without repeating the default parameters of the superclass):

```
abstract class SuperClazz(id: String = "")
case class SubClazz(name: String = "", size: Int = 0) extends SuperClazz
val sub = SubClazz(id = "123", size = 2)
```

Comment: Not possible with regular scala syntax. With macros, this might be possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it's not possible to do without repeating parameters from super class. It is due to the fact that case classes are special type of scala classes. It is beacuse compiler implicitly generates companion extractor object with *apply* and *unapply* methods and in those methods it will be no parameter that is not specified in class parameters.

Consider this code snippet

```
abstract class SuperClazz(id: String = "")
class SubClazz(name: String,id: String) extends SuperClazz {
    override def toString: String = "name: " + name + ",id: " + id
}
object SubClazz {
    def apply(name: String = "", id: String = "") = new SubClazz(name, id)
}
```

It's shorter and simpler ( and little bit  different regarding `toString` method ) version of what is being created when

```
case class SubClazz(name: String, id: String) extends SubClazz
```

is called.